# Split lines from stream into words to map their length and value

Tags: java, java-8

From given text, by using stream operations, I need to create a Map where word length is a key and List of words is a value. I need to filter out words that are no longer than 4 characters.

```
String text = "random.txt";
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(text))
Map<Integer,List<String>> map = lines.map(line -> line.split("[\\s]+"))
                                .filter(word -> word.length > 4)
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                    word -> Integer.valueOf(word[0].length()),
                                    Collectors.mapping(word -> word[0], Collectors.toList()))
                                 );
```

I must be understanding something wrong, the way I used filter is not working - throws IndexOutOfBoundsException. How should i go about excluding words that are less than 4 characters long?

I was only able to figure out how to map the first word from each line. What should I change to map
every word?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes after the code.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Tester {
    private static Map<Integer, List<String>> byLines(String filePath) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            return lines.flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")))
                        .filter(word -> word.length() > 4)
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(word -> word.length()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Map<Integer, List<String>> map = byLines("random.txt");
            map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.printf("%d: %s%n", key, value));
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You need to call method `flatMap` to create a `Stream` that concatenates all the words from each line, thus converting a `Stream` of lines of text to a stream of words.

Method `split` (of class `String`) returns an array.
Method `stream` (of class `Arrays`) creates a `Stream` from an array.
Method `flatMap` concatenates all the words from all the lines and creates a `Stream` containing all the individual words in file *random.txt*.
Then you keep all words that contain more than 4 characters.
Then you collect the words according to your requirements, i.e. a `Map` where the [map] key is the length and the [map] value is a `List` containing all the words having the same length.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<Integer, List<String>> map = Stream.of("hello", "hell", "gun", "chicken", "building", "process", "world")
            .filter(pred -> pred.length() > 4)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));
```